# CSS opacity for linear-gradient background?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a div which has a background of:

```
background: linear-gradient(120deg, #6971a2 0%, white 80%);
```

I'd like to add opacity functionality to this background whilst not affecting the text inside the div.

I'm aware of RGBA. However, I'm fairly sure linear-gradient cannot be used with it?

Thanks!

Comment: `However, I'm fairly sure linear-gradient cannot be used with it?` --> did you try or it's a simple guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any CSS [`<color>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) as a stop on a a `linear-gradient`, including `#hexa` and `rgba()` which allow you to gradate between opacities.

The transparency of an element’s background (or its background gradient) will have no effect on its content.

Comment: However there's a gotcha to it too. Which is explained well on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/thing-know-gradients-transparent-black/)